# Is there any way to highlight default vim keyword without using match?

Tags: vim

I'm making custom .vim syntax highlighting, and there is one problem with syntax file. Here's the code:

```
syn keyword vimKeyword contains contained
```

When i'm trying to open .vim files it gives an error, because `contains` is an actual keyword:

```
Error detected while processing .vim/syntax/vim.vim
E395: contains argument not accepted here
```

Is it possible to highlight default vim keywords without using `syn match`?

Comment: if you are talking about literally just changing the background on certain words/syntax, you can just, for instance, `hi Comment ctermbg=135`

Comment: Thank you for reply, but what can i do when `contains` is not only .vim keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:help E789`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#E789) mentions this:

> Note that when you have a keyword that is the same as an option (even
>   one that isn't allowed here), you can not use it.  Use a match
>   instead.

That said, what seems to work for me is defining just a single keyword `contains`:

```
syn keyword vimKeyword contains
```

Additional keywords can be defined via separate `:syn keyword vimKeyword` commands, as they are cummulative.

Another trick is defining the keyword with an optional tail, but keeping it empty:

```
syn keyword vimKeyword contains[] contained
```

But as both of these are (mis-)using implementation specifics of the Vimscript parser, I would **not** rely on them, and instead use `:syntax match`, as documented.